# Define default value for plain input field (Templavoila)

Tags: typo3, default-value, templavoila

I tried to set the field "Sample Data" on the "Configuration" page when mapping a data element with Templavoila. But it seems it is used for something else.

Is it possible to define default values for fields like "Plain input field"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Templavoila DS/TO editor, select your field and add following to "Form"
`<default>Your default value</default>`

Heres an example:

[image: Add default value to Form field]